# How to detect burned areas from Landsat or MODIS datasets using ILWIS?

Tags: remote-sensing, modis, landsat, ilwis

I'm trying to find a simple tutorial on how to detect and map burned areas from/with [ILWIS](http://www.ilwis.org/) . I use Landsat 5/7 or MODIS for detection.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, mapping burned areas--especially across large geographic areas--is not a simple task.  However, there is a lot of good documentation on how burned area products are created in peer reviewed publications.

For a regional perspective, I would refer you to the [Monitoring trends in burn severity (MTBS)](http://www.mtbs.gov/index.html) site.  MTBS utilizes Landsat data to map all fires from 1984 - 2010 within the USA.  They have extensive resources on their methods [here](http://www.mtbs.gov/methods.html) and refer interested parties to the following publication for further details:

> Eidenshink, J., Schwind, B., Brewer, K., Zhu, Z. L., Quayle, B., &
>   Howard, S. (2007). A project for monitoring trends in burn severity.
>   The Journal of the Association for Fire Ecology, 3(01), 3.

**Burned area boundary as detected from postfire imagery**
[image]

---

For a global perspective, check out [MODIS Active Fire & Burned Area Products](http://modis-fire.umd.edu/index.html) from the University of Maryland.  There is also rigorous documentation on the methods used and refer people to the following publication:

- For Active Fires:

> Giglio, L., Csiszar, I., Justice, C.O. 2006. Global distribution and
>   seasonality of active fires as observed with the Terra and Aqua MODIS
>   sensors. Journal of Geophysical Research - Biogeosciences, Vol 111,
>   G02016, doi:10.1029/2005JG000142.
>
> Giglio, L., Descloitres, J., Justice, C.O., Kaufman, Y. 2003. An
>   enhanced contextual fire detection algorithm for MODIS. Remote Sensing
>   of Environment, 87:273-282.

- For burned area products:

> D.P. Roy, L. Boschetti, C.O. Justice, J. Ju, The Collection 5 MODIS
>   Burned Area Product - Global Evaluation by Comparison with the MODIS
>   Active Fire Product, 2008. Remote Sensing of Environment, 112,
>   3690-3707
>
> Roy, D.P., Jin, Y., Lewis, P.E., Justice, C.O. 2005. Prototyping a
>   global algorithm for systematic fire-affected area mapping using MODIS
>   time series data.Remote Sensing of Environment, 97:137-162.

**August 2007 fires in Greece, as mapped by the MCD45 product.**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Seems that the main issue is to find an algorithm (and it seems that you do not have one). If you have needed algorithm, it doesn't matter in which image-processing soft to use it. Check out [FIRMS](https://earthdata.nasa.gov/data/near-real-time-data/firms) site for fire data derived from MODIS. There you can find [list of publications](https://earthdata.nasa.gov/data/near-real-time-data/firms/publications) that may proof useful to you. There is a great article *Giglio, L., van derWerf, G. R., Randerson, J. T., Collatz, G. J., and Kasibhatla, P. 2006. Global estimation of burned area using MODIS active fire observations. Atmospheric Chemistry and Physics 6:957-974. doi:10.5194/acp-6-957-2006.* Also take a look at [this article](http://gis-lab.info/qa/fires-perm.html) with a more step-by-step guide. It is in Russian, but I hope that google-translate will help you.

Also if you have an academic interest I may provide you with contacts of scientist who have studied this subject a lot.

Comment: +1 FIRMS is a great resource